# When dynamically appending a div and setting a class, my div gets put into class name AND appended

Tags: javascript, html

Some very strange behaviour here: 
What I am doing:

1. dynamically setting class name to a `td`
2. dynamically appending a `div` to the `td`

My then resulting `td` ends up like this:

> ```
> <td class="GSCBRI<div><p>Telefon : </p></div> 17">
>     <div>
>         <p>Telefon : </p>
>     </div>
> </td>
> ```

> ```
> <td class="GSCBRI 17">
>     <div>
>         <p>Telefon : </p>
>     </div>
> </td>
> ```

Naturally my code:

```
row.childNodes.forEach((el) => {
  el.setAttribute('class', `${row.childNodes[0].innerHTML} ${i}`);
  i++;
  let htmlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let htmlp = document.createElement('p');
  htmlp.innerText = 'Telefon : ';
  htmlDiv.appendChild(htmlp);
  htmlDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
  el.appendChild(htmlDiv);
})
```

If I comment out the el.appendChild(htmlDiv) it does not interfere with my class, but then I of course do not get the `div`

How is my `div` getting caught up in my class?

Comment: sorry,I have to edit, misclick

Comment: Please may you add the JS used?

Comment: The code ```el.setAttribute('class', `${row.childNodes[0].innerHTML} ${i}`);``` **explicitly** uses the `innerHTML` of `row.childNodes[0]` as text within the value you're setting for the `class` attribute. Assuming `row.childNodes[0]` is the `td` (which seems likely), that `innerHTML` contains the markup for the `div` that's inside the `td`.  If that's not what you want, then that's the code to change.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is absolutely what is happening. 
If I inspect the first element I can see the class is getting appended as I expect and theen it starts adding the full `td` elements. 
Thank you T.J Crowder :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.childNodes`, it will be easier with using `.children`. It returns all of the children as HTML elements instead of the HTML nodes.

```js
let row = document.querySelector('tr');

[...row.children].forEach((el,i) => {
  el.setAttribute('class', `${el.innerHTML} ${i}`);
  let htmlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let htmlp = document.createElement('p');
  htmlp.innerText = 'Telefon : ';
  htmlDiv.appendChild(htmlp);
  htmlDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
  el.appendChild(htmlDiv);
})
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>GSCBRI</td>
    <td>GSCBRA</td>
    <td>GSCBRE</td>
    <td>GSCBRU</td>
    <td>GSCBRO</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on T.J. Crowder's helpful observation I fixed the code like this:

```
//define className outside of forEach loop
let userName = row.childNodes[0].innerText
row.childNodes.forEach((el) => {
//use predefined className to append to class
  el.setAttribute('class', `${userName} ${i}`);
  i++;
  let htmlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let htmlp = document.createElement('p');
  htmlp.innerText = 'Telefon : ';
  htmlDiv.appendChild(htmlp);
  htmlDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
  el.appendChild(htmlDiv);
})
```